# How to recover soft bad sectors

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, bad-sectors, bad-blocks

How to get rid of soft bad sectors obtained from cloning a faulty disc?
I have a EFI HDD with some bad sectors from a DELL computer. It's been causing headache for quite some time. So want to replace it. Because of that bad sectors Macrium couldn't do direct cloning. Hence I found a work around doing image/restore. But now I have those sectors (soft though) on this new drive. I'm assuming if those sectors on OEM drive are real, physical bad sectors, OK, I won't be able to fix them, but what about those soft on new drive. Please help get rid of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got my question answered at another forum. The issue is resolved with chkdsc /b.